# Expose a handler function to Lambda from a Docker Image

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I'm trying to build a hello world example of a docker image powering a lambda function.

My docker image houses a NPM project that looks like this:

```
project
│   app.js
|   Dockerfile
|   package.json
|   package-lock.json
```

The code inside app.js is:

```
// app.js
module.exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
  console.log('Code Running Inside Handler Function');
  console.log(event);
  console.log(context);
  return "Hello World.";
}
```

I dockerize my app with this CMD layer in my docker file:

```
CMD [ "app.lambdaHandler" ]
```

I upload the docker image to AWS and try to run it as a lambda function. However I get the follow runtime error:

> Cannot find module '/project/app.lambdaHandler'

How am I supposed to expose 'lambdaHandler' to aws?

Edit to include my docker file:

```
FROM node:16

COPY app.js ./

CMD [ "app.lambdaHandler" ]
```

Comment: What is your dockerfile?

Comment: @Marcin Added it to the question

Comment: Why your dockerfile does not follow AWS template for lambda containers?

Comment: @Marcin Does it have to? I thought we were allowed to use any image we wanted. However the reason is I had a bit of trouble getting Tensorflow to compile with the AWS image. I didn't look into it much as the standard node:16 worked fine. If it's a requirement to use the AWS image I will look into it more.

Comment: You can use custom image, but you have to setup it. For example have to install lambda runtime interface client among other things.

Comment: Oh thank you, that probably answers my question. I will look into it.

Comment: Sure. If so I will make answer with some extra links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [custom image for AWS lambda container](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-create-from-alt), some steps have to be undertaken to prepare it for a lambda environment. They include, among other things:

- Installing the [runtime interface client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-images.html#runtimes-api-client).
- Setting the ENTRYPOINT property to **invoke** the runtime interface client.

But the easiest way would be to use AWS provided [base images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html#images-create-from-base).